# Selecting the top 10 best candidates for an experiment

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multiple-comparisons

I'm a newbie here. But I want to select 10 retailers to onboard in an experiment, but that retailers need to be important enough to be there and bad enough to drive an impact.

So in my dataset I will have the following:

- retailer name;
- number of times a user interacts with their products;
- number of times a user buys their product;
- total gmv that retailer generates.

Ao a bad retailer will be a retailer that a user interacts a lot but for some reason user doesn't buy their product. And the retailer needs to be good enough for me to invest on him.

Do you know if there is any method to evaluate this?

Many thanks

Comment: this doesn't sound like a stats question to me.

Comment: I agree with Aksakal. I hardly see anything related to statistics/ml in this problem.